# Web-RTC HTML5 WEB SOCKET Server Client Example

Tags: html, websocket, video-streaming, html5-video, webrtc

I want to make connection with two browsers on two different computer. This computer are under the same network.(with private ıp address) I want to use html5 and web-rtc. Does Web-RTC use Web Sockets ? How can i  develop this application step by step ? Any suggestion ? Any tutorial ? I am getting two videos on the same PC with all of the tutorial.. But I want to two different pc.

Answer (score 1):

WebRTC utilizes a signalling server and mechanism for session information exchange. WebSockets are commonly used for this purpose(but other options exists). In Any of the options, there exists a server that will assist in exchanging the session information. Once all informaiton is exchanged, then media can be begin streaming between the clients.

There are a couple tutorials on how to do this but [I like Sam Dutton's](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/) and [this one on WebRTC Hacks](http://webrtchacks.com/signalling-options-for-webrtc-applications/).

[WebRTC.io](https://github.com/webRTC/webRTC.io) is very simple to set up and use for signalling for two clients. Personally, I created my own websocket server in .NET using [SuperSocket](https://supersocket.codeplex.com/) but again, there are a plethora of options.

Answer (score 0):

I dont realy know if RTC use Web Sockets but i would start with choose a programming language for the Server.

You could do it with JavaScript ( Node.js ) as well as with Java ( GlassFish Server + Endpoint ) and many more.

The Clientside would in most cases look like this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_websocket.htm

The Client always is in JavaScript! Just search for something like 'JavaScript Websocket example' on Google.